# Fetch file from S3 and feed it into a python script

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I have a local NiFi flow which is reading files locally and feeding it into a python script via cmd line arguments. However, I now would like NiFi to read other files stored in `Amazon S3` and feed them into my python script.

I have used `ListS3` and `FetchS3` processors to get my files and I have access to variables like `s3.bucket` and `filename` which exactly match the files stored in `S3`.

I am also using `MergeContent` to merge multiple files coming in from the `FetchS3` processor. My python script does take in multiple files like this:

`python myScript.py -f ~/temp/file1.txt -k ~/temp/file2.txt`

The python script reads the files to process data in it. But, with `S3` no matter which format I put in the `file path` I always get this error:

`Error=[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myS3bucket/s3-files/File1.txt'`

while trying to run something like this:

`python myScript.py -f ${s3.bucket}/${filename}` inside the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your files, once in NiFi from S3, are managed via the Content Repository and don't by default exist on your file system in the same locations. You can use PutFile to write the files to disk, then call your script.